# Why do we have kuladevatha, grama devatha, when ista devatha does the same job ?

Tags: rituals, worship

AFAIK, based on one's own understanding and spiritual level, one may find love on one avatar who may be called ista devatha. Why do we have kula devatha/family god and grama devatha/village god worship when we know God is one and all His forms are equal?

Grama devatha usually will be shakti or a god in veera form and kuladevatha may be the ista devatha of father or forefathers or may had been chosen for a particular cause or a reason. Even in puja I see people worship all these three, why is this practice introduced?

Comment: One reason: perhaps it is to pass the culture and beliefs through various age. For example, worshipping Grama Devatha is a way of passing down the culture of that village down the generation and worshipping of kula devatha is a way of passing down the traditions of the lineage down the generations. However u said rightly that God is One and all His forms are equal. Therefore if done with earnest, then prayer to One God is enough to liberate us from the bondage. :)

Comment: @Sai can you add some more detail info and make this as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we Hindus pray all our Kuldevta, gramdevta and Ishtdevta during any auspicious activity as they are three gods who are present always around us.

we invite other devi devta's who are nearest to us and are always there for other auspicious occasions.

its like how you can put, as you have a dinner hosted at your house for people from far, would you not like to call your neighbors? especially when they have protected you, your forefathers, and your statesmen all these years?

And regarding one god formula, Isht is one, but we pray different forms of him, according to our desire so that it gives a sense of satisfaction to the inner god in us, and hence we have more energy to fulfill any work.